# apt-get remove <package> installs alternative package

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

Amusingly, whenever I try to remove a package using apt-get on Ubuntu 11.04, apt-get attempts to install an alternative package in addition to removing the requested package(s).  Here are a couple examples:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-40-64-142:/$ sudo apt-get remove w3m
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lynx lynx-cur
Suggested packages:
  lynx-cur-wrapper
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  w3m
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lynx lynx-cur
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 105 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,069 kB of archives.
After this operation, 406 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.

ubuntu@ip-10-40-64-142:/$ sudo apt-get remove firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  epiphany-browser epiphany-browser-data epiphany-gecko evince evince-common gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10
  gir1.2-json-glib-1.0 gnome-doc-utils gnome-js-common gnome-user-guide gvfs gvfs-backends indicator-application libappindicator1
  libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libbluetooth3 libcdio-cdda0 libcdio-paranoia0 libcdio10 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libevdocument3 libevview3 libgdu0 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-port0 libgvfscommon0 libindicator3
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libnautilus-extension1 libopenobex1 libpoppler-glib6 libseed0 libspectre1 libt1-5 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common obex-data-server policykit-1-gnome python-libxml2 yelp yelp-xsl
Suggested packages:
  epiphany-extensions unrar poppler-data nautilus gphoto2 gtkam libspectre1-dbg ttf-dejavu
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox firefox-globalmenu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  epiphany-browser epiphany-browser-data epiphany-gecko evince evince-common gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10
  gir1.2-json-glib-1.0 gnome-doc-utils gnome-js-common gnome-user-guide gvfs gvfs-backends indicator-application libappindicator1
  libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libbluetooth3 libcdio-cdda0 libcdio-paranoia0 libcdio10 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libevdocument3 libevview3 libgdu0 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-port0 libgvfscommon0 libindicator3
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libnautilus-extension1 libopenobex1 libpoppler-glib6 libseed0 libspectre1 libt1-5 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common obex-data-server policykit-1-gnome python-libxml2 yelp yelp-xsl
0 upgraded, 46 newly installed, 2 to remove and 104 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 90.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Here is output of --version

```
ubuntu@ip-10-40-64-142:/$ apt-get --version
apt 0.8.13.2ubuntu4.6 for amd64 compiled on Jun 15 2012 14:55:09
Supported modules:
*Ver: Standard .deb
*Pkg:  Debian dpkg interface (Priority 30)
 S.L: 'deb' Standard Debian binary tree
 S.L: 'deb-src' Standard Debian source tree
 Idx: Debian Source Index
 Idx: Debian Package Index
 Idx: Debian Translation Index
 Idx: Debian dpkg status file
```

Is there some obscure config or known bug that causes this?

(I know that 11.04 is disgustingly old, but I do not have the luxury of upgrading dist in this case.)

Comment: You have terribly messed up your system apparently. The only correct solution would be a fresh install of a supported release. Since you say upgrading often isn't an option I suggest an LTS. You shouldn't be running a non LTS if you can't upgrade, they go out of date too quickly.

Comment: I completely agree with running an LTS version and echo that recommendation to anyone coming across this thread.  Unfortunately, as I alluded to, I did not have the ability to do that in this particular case (which pains me greatly). Thankfully, the system was not terribly messed up, as noted in the answer below.

Comment: @Seth I doubt system reinstallation is usually necessary for this sort of problem. When a manually installed (i.e., not installed automatically as a dependency) package, or sometimes even a dependency of such a package, declares a "depends" relationship (i.e., strong dependency, not just "recommends"), subsequent transactions will attempt to preserve the dependency. If the dependency is a virtual package, alternative software may be installed to replace what's being removed. (And if it's a metapackage... well, you get the idea.) Based on the OP's answer, I think that's what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by the package `update-sun-jre`.  Removing that package fixed the issue.  This was a 3rd party package from http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php?t=en.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for figuring out the root of your problem. Something to watch for in your future endeavors - meta-packages can cause this issue as well; for example if you installed the 'lubuntu' meta-package and attempted to change/remove components, many have automatic replacements that will leave you running in circles as you attempt to adjust your installed packages.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  Admittedly, uninstalling packages from 3rd party repos should have been my first step.  However, I did not think packages could even set up their dependencies in a way to cause this kind of behavior.